# Can multiple Support Vector Machine models achieve the same accuracy as one deep neural network?

Tags: neural-networks, svm

Assume that we have one deep neural network with an input for images. That deep neural network can classify images.

On the other side, we have multiple Support Vector Machines that classify parts of an image.
If the image pale, does the image have two round circles etc. All these properties are fit into another SVM that classify the output.

**Question:**

Can multiple Support Vector Machine models achieve the same accuracy as one deep neural network?

In my opinion, a Support Vector Machine is actually one layer neural network with `sign` as activation function.

I have tried Fisherfaces with SVM and it works like a charm.

**Edit:**

Just because one up voted this question, I will post the resource to the Fisherfaces algorithm

https://github.com/DanielMartensson/MataveID/blob/master/examples/fisherfacesExample.md